# IdentityServer4 and Azure AD - Getting blank page 404 to login.live after entering credentials

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, identityserver4

I am trying to setup Azure AD as an external provider for IdentityServer4 in a development environment. Google and Facebook providers already are hooked up successfully.
I'm directed to the login page on login.microsoft.com where I enter my login id and select an MS account, it then directs me to login.live.com as a blank page (404) instead of redirecting back to my IdentityServer instance.

I've tried a bunch of things but have had no luck.

Do I need to enable Enterprise Applications in Azure?

Am I missing something?

**IdentityServer URL:**
http://localhost:5000

**IdentityServer URL:**
http://localhost:47740

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
...
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateAzureAdOptions(clientId, tenantId));
...

 public static OpenIdConnectOptions CreateAzureAdOptions(string clientId, string tenentId)
    {
        return new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            DisplayName = "Azure Active Directory",
            AuthenticationScheme = "Azure",
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenentId),
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            Scope = { "openid" },
            SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Based on the description, you want to IdentityServer to support Microsoft Account, however you were register the app on Azure portal. This doesn't support Microsoft Account. To interact with both Microsoft Account and work/school account, you need to use the Azure AD V2.0 endpoint which register the app from [New App Register Portal](apps.dev.microsoft.com). Refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview) about Azure AD V2.0 endpoint.

Comment: Perhaps you are seeing this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/978 . Which is fixed for Azure sts, but still errors out if account is a Live account and not AzureAD one. This is one workaround that seems to work for live accounts, although it's a little hackish: https://github.com/mclark1129/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/AzureAd_CustomStateDataFormat

Comment: The authority string will be like this:  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id here>/v2.0/"

Answer (score 5):

This probably is related to the size of the url when returning from AAD. This is actualy a `404.15` IIS specific status code. If you have a lot of claims returned from your External identity provider (ie a profile image base64) then you will always hit the cap in url length [HTTP Error 404.15 - query url too long RSS](https://forums.asp.net/t/2024846.aspx?HTTP+Error+404+15+query+url+too+long).

IdenitityServer4 has a topic in the docs that addresses this issue by using the distributed cache underneath. It is located under [Sign-in with External Identity Providers - State, URL length, and ISecureDataFormat](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signin_external_providers.html#state-url-length-and-isecuredataformat)

**Abstract**:

> Fortunately, IdentityServer provides an implementation of this for you, backed by the `IDistributedCache` implementation registered in the DI container (e.g. the standard `MemoryDistributedCache`). To use the IdentityServer provided secure data format implementation, simply call the `AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache` extension method on the `IServiceCollection` when configuring DI. If no parameters are passed, then all OpenID Connect handlers configured will use the IdentityServer provided secure data format implementation.